# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and ThreadAbortedException

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, json.net, task

In Xamarin project I have PCL library with the following code.

We define a `ConcurrentQueue<SyncRequest>`. For which on object initialization the consumer `Task` has been attached:

```
_syncConsumer = new Task(
                ProcessSyncQueue,
                _syncConsumerCancellationTokenSource.Token);
_syncConsumer.Start();
```

The `ProcessSyncQueue` method scans synchronization queue and call `GetSyncableEntity` method:

```
private async void ProcessSyncQueue()
{
    while (true)
    {
         SyncRequest syncRequest;
         if (_syncQueue.TryDequeue(out syncRequest))
         {
             var syncableEntity = GetSyncableEntity(syncRequest);
         }
    }
}
```

GetSyncableEntity in turn performs Json deserialization:

```
private T GetSyncableEntity(SyncRequest syncRequest)
{
    T syncableEntity = default(T);

    try
    {
       syncableEntity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(syncRequest.SynchronizationContent);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

    return syncableEntity;
 }
```

On this step we receive `ThreadAbortedException` with 'Thread was being aborted' message.
Stacktrace:

```
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.FinishReadStringIntoBuffer(Int32 charPos, Int32 initialPosition, Int32 lastWritePosition)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringIntoBuffer(Char quote)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseProperty()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseObject()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndAssert()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
```

Can anyone help us to understand what is going on and how it should be deserialized?

UPDATE:
I post a bit more code, as reviewers suggested I deleted `CancellationTokenSource`, use `Task.Run` to initialize consumer and `await` it.
And created some test implementation like this:

```
    protected void RequestSynchronizationFor(
        string synchronizationKey,
        T entity)
    {
        if (!_isInitialized)
        {
            InitializeSyncRequestsQueue();
        }

        _syncQueue.Enqueue(GetSyncRequest(synchronizationKey, entity));
    }
```

So we request entity to be synchronized calling `RequestSynchronizationFor` method. If it is cold run we initialize the queue from db calling `InitializeSyncRequestsQueue` and await `Task.Run` consumer thread.

```
    private async void InitializeSyncRequestsQueue()
    {
        var syncRequests = GetSyncedRequests();

        foreach (var syncRequest in syncRequests)
        {
            _syncQueue.Enqueue(syncRequest);
        }

        await Task.Run(ProcessSyncQueue);
    }
```

Consumer task as before does the same things:

```
 private async Task ProcessSyncQueue()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            SyncRequest syncRequest;
            if (_syncQueue.TryDequeue(out syncRequest))
            {
                var syncableEntity = GetSyncableEntity(syncRequest);
            }
        }
    }
```

Still got the same exception. Not sure if it is sensible, but I am running the code from the unit-test. Any suggestions?

UPDATE2:

After I did changes I posted in first 'UPDATE', the call stack was changed a bit as well:

```
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.get_MetadataPropertyHandling()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
```

UPDATE 3:
I extract all the code in fake service and still have the same exception, while trying to deserialize:

```
public class JsonDeserializeService<T>
{
    private readonly bool _isInitialized;

    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<SyncRequest> _syncQueue;

    public JsonDeserializeService()
    {
        _isInitialized = false;
        _syncQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<SyncRequest>();
    }

    public void RequestSynchronizationFor(
        string synchronizationKey,
        T entity)
    {
        if (!_isInitialized)
        {
            InitializeSyncRequestsQueue();
        }

        _syncQueue.Enqueue(GetSyncRequest(synchronizationKey, entity));
    }

    private async void InitializeSyncRequestsQueue()
    {
        var syncRequests = Enumerable.Empty<SyncRequest>();

        foreach (var syncRequest in syncRequests)
        {
            _syncQueue.Enqueue(syncRequest);
        }

        await Task.Run(ProcessSyncQueue);
    }

    private async Task ProcessSyncQueue()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            SyncRequest syncRequest;
            if (_syncQueue.TryDequeue(out syncRequest))
            {
                var syncableEntity = GetSyncableEntity(syncRequest);
            }
        }
    }

    private T GetSyncableEntity(SyncRequest syncRequest)
    {
        T syncableEntity = default(T);

        try
        {
            syncableEntity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(syncRequest.SynchronizationContent);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

        return syncableEntity;
    }

    private SyncRequest GetSyncRequest(string synchronizationKey, T entity)
    {
        return new SyncRequest()
        {
            SynchronizationContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity),
            SynchronizationDelayUntil = DateTime.Now
        };
    }
}
```

Triggered from unit-test:

```
    public void Syncable_Service_Should_Not_Generate_Exception()
    {
        var syncService = new JsonDeserializeService<FakeSyncableEntity>();
        syncService.RequestSynchronizationFor("syncKey", new FakeSyncableEntity() { Content = "Content" });
    }
```

Comment: I think you should link more code and try to isolate the issue. From what you are showing it's hard to tell what could be aborting threads. Following _syncConsumerCancellationTokenSource.Token will be the offender i think

Comment: Does this work outside of ConcurrentQueue?

Comment: You should never use "new Task" – use Task.Run(ProcessSyncQueue, _syncConsumerCancellationTokenSource.Token) instead. Also what happens to your _syncConsumer object? Do you await it? The error message may hint at the task object being disposed when it's still running and its associated thread being aborted.

Comment: @Dbl I update my question

Comment: @ckuri did as you suggested and it is still the same

Comment: @EmmieLewis-Briggman not sure what do you mean? should I try to use another data structure internally?

Comment: Where does the _syncConsumerCancellationTokenSource come from?  Is it a local variable or not?  (I guess it is an instance variable because of the underscore)  How long does _syncConsumerCancellationTokenSource live?

Comment: @ViktorSeifert yes, it was local variable, just initialized in ctor, but now I deleted it in my 'UPDATE'

Comment: @ViktorSeifert please see my last update 'UPDATE 3', I included all the code in one fake service

Comment: Ok, I finally got it, my test ends and then kill all background tasks

Comment: @JevgenijNekrasov consider posting your findings as an answer (you're allowed to answer your own questions).  Since this question got some upvotes it seems it might be useful to other people.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this behavior is very simple.
Your test ends ealier than the async task. When test ends it raises ThreadAbortException for child threads.

You need to call task.Wait() to make main thread wait for task completion.